# I am passing variable $input from controller to view in laravel and it shows an error undefined variable $input in View

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am passing variable `$input` from controller to view in laravel 5.0 and it shows an error undefined variable `$input` in View. Can anyone suggest something ??  when you print_`r($input)` in controller it gives an array but `$input` is not giving its value in view. Code works fine if we use `$_POST` since it is a global varaiable instead of any other variable.

controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\show;
use App\register;

class User extends BaseController
{


    public function store()
{       
     $input = Input::all();





    return view('show',(array)$input);
}

}
 view show

<html>
    <head>






    </head>
    <body>
              <div>


            Name:  <label><?php echo $input['EmailID']?></label><br>




          </div>
                      </body>
                      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this instead.

`return view('show', ['input' => $input]);`

please refer to this documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views

Answer (score 1):

And there is even more possibilities... :-)

You can also use the 'with' method

```
return view('view_name')
   ->with('param_name1', 'param_value1')
   ->with('param_name2', 'param_value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store()
{       
   $input = Request::all();
   return view('show', compact('input'));
}
```

In views:

```
Name:  <label>{{ $input->EmailID }}</label>
```

Also, make sure that you are getting **EmailID** in the request.